# Kata answer similar to test answer but test failing

Tags: javascript

I am doing the kata Christmas Tree on Codewars : https://www.codewars.com/kata/christmas-tree/train/javascript

Even if my result and the test result are similar, the test keeps on failing. Could anyone help me to understand ?

Many thanks.

```js
    function christmasTree(height) {
      let tree = "";
      let leaf = "*";
      let leafNumber = 3;
      let space = "\xa0";
      let spaceNumber = 0;
      for (var i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
        if (i === 1) {
          spaceNumber = height - 1;
          tree =
            space.repeat(spaceNumber) + leaf + space.repeat(spaceNumber);
          spaceNumber--;
        } else {
          tree +=
            "\n" +
            space.repeat(spaceNumber) +
            leaf.repeat(leafNumber) +
            space.repeat(spaceNumber);
          leafNumber += 2;
          spaceNumber--;
        }
      }
      return tree;
    }

console.log(christmasTree(2));
```

Comment: Can you provide more information in your question about what exactly is failing?

Comment: the test is working for value 0 and 1, then it fails for values that are superior, it gives me the output of my function and the expected output but both are similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tests failed because you are using the non-breaking space. The error code on Codewars is showing:

> Expected: `" * \\n***"`, instead got: `" * \\n***"`

You can use an actual space instead:

```
let space = " ";
```

[image]

EDIT: `"\xa0" == " "` is `false`

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked with me.

It's better to divide your problem to function to make it easier to read and solve.

```js
function addSpace(word, size){
  const rem = size - word.length
  return ' '.repeat(rem/2)+word+' '.repeat(rem/2)
}

function christmasTree(height) {
  let treeLen = (2 * height) - 1
  let tree = ""
  for(let i = 0;i < height;i++){
    tree += addSpace('*'.repeat(1+(i*2)),treeLen)
    tree += (i == height - 1)? "" : "\n"
  }
  return tree
}


console.log(christmasTree(9))
```

Comment: While this solves the problem, it does not really answers the OP's question.